# Zend AMF + Zend Website

Tags: zend-framework, zend-amf

I will be developing a front-end website and a back-end in Adobe Air.
So I would like to have a Zend_amf to communicate to Air
And a regular zend web application for my website.

Does anyone know if I could do this in one Zend framework installation?
I can't add any subdomains or anything so I don't think I can get 2 installations to work.
Or am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need two installations.  Simply provide a gateway point for AMF to connect to that resides in your ZF application.

Comment: How does one create a gateway point? Would it be in the Controller? Does the view  need to be disabled?

Comment: It can be in the controller, but generally we recommend having a simple endpoint script that may or may not bootstrap the request.  If you know exactly where your gateway is (which you do) there is no point in loading up all the controllers and views by running it through the MVC system.